# Cross Referencing with the xr Package in Overleaf (and custom Section Names)

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf, multiple-files, xr

I followed [the Overleaf guide to cross-referencing between different LaTeX documents](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf#Creating_the_latexmkrc_file). This works really well - if I use `\cref{eqn:supplement-equation1}` in my `main.tex` document, it will correctly render the reference to that equation in my `supplement.tex` file.

This is the case even for equations for which I have defined a custom naming scheme: Instead of **"Eq. 1"**, I have **"Eq. SI-1"**:

```latex
\renewcommand{\theequation}{SI-\arabic{equation}}
```

However, this does not work for custom section names defined in `supplement.tex`. I get two cases:

1. If I define section names in `supplement.tex` as

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Unit \arabic{section}}
```

they are correctly referenced in `main.tex` as **"Unit 1"**, etc. However, this messes up the TOC in `supplement.tex`:

[image]

2. If I define section names in `supplement.tex` as

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Unit \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother
```

they are referenced in `main.tex` as **"section 1"**, etc. At least the TOC in `supplement.tex` now looks fine:

[image]

How can I make sure that a reference to a section from from my `supplement.tex` file is rendered as **"Unit 1"** in my `main.tex` file, while maintaining the TOC?

MWE (also available at https://www.overleaf.com/read/xywgwfjgbxjt):

`main.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% cross-referencing
% https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf#Creating_the_latexmkrc_file
\usepackage{cleveref}
\input{preamble}
\myexternaldocument{supplement}

\begin{document}

A test cross-reference to an equation in the supplement: \cref{eqn:supplement1}. And to a section \cref{sec:sec1}.

\end{document}
```

`preamble.tex`:

```latex
% https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf

\usepackage{xr-hyper} % enable cross-references across different files, must be loaded before 'hyperref'

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{
\typeout{(#1)}
\@addtofilelist{#1}
\IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
\externaldocument{#1}%
\addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
\addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
}
```

`supplement.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% custom section names
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Unit \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother

% custom equation names
\renewcommand{\theequation}{SI-\arabic{equation}}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}

\section{sec1}
\label{sec:sec1}

\begin{equation}
a = b
\label{eqn:supplement1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it should imho work, if it doesn't you should show a small but complete example here (do not link to some external project or template).

Comment: as I wrote: do not link to some external project. I don't follow such links.

Comment: Ok, added the text to the main question.

Comment: you must load cleveref also in the supplement file, so it produces the labels it needs.

Comment: Ah - that works for equations, great! However, for custom section names it does not. Any ideas here? (I added the custom section code to the main question).

Comment: put a bit more effort in your question. Try the stuff before posting it.

Comment: I added the results from some trial-and-error, additional context, two screenshots and updated the MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External references with xr can only work, if internal references work. So at first get the references in the supplement right. You can use the `\labelformat` command to change the way how something is referenced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% custom section names
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Unit \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\labelformat{section}{Unit~#1}
\makeatother

% custom equation names
\renewcommand{\theequation}{SI-\arabic{equation}}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{sec1}
\label{sec:sec1}

\begin{equation}
a = b
\label{eqn:supplement1}
\end{equation}


\cref{eqn:supplement1}, \ref{sec:sec1}, \cref{sec:sec1}

\end{document}
```

[image]