# Multi-Line Section Heading with Custom Title

Tags: sectioning, journal-publishing

How do I get a section heading of the kind:

**Supplementary Note 1** 
**Some Example Heading Name**

with the ToC only showing the section name, not the "Supplementary Note":

**1 Some Example Heading Name.............................1**

?

Edit: Since my above description was evidently not clear enough, here is a rendered example of what I would like to have:

[image]

I already have:

```latex
% custom section designations
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Supplementary Note \csname the#1\endcsname:} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/693618
\makeatother
```

But this does not allow me to break the heading properly.

Comment: `\section[short in toc]{long long long in document}`

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not result in the combination I need.

Comment: Then provide code which demonstrates the problem. Right now, all anybody can do is guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this works for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\large\bfseries\filright}{\bfseries Supplementary Note \thesection}{0pt}{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Is there a quick way to ensure \cref{section1} would also reference this correctly?

Comment: You can use `\crefname{section}{supplementary note}{supplementary notes}`